# Is it possible to use Python lxml on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, lxml

Can I use Python lxml on Google App Engine? (or do I have to use Beautiful Soup?)

I have started using Beautiful Soup but it seems slow.  I am just starting to play with the idea of "screen scraping" data from other websites to create some sort of "mash-up".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT**: The `lxml` library [is now supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

---

Short answer: [you can't](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=18).

From AppEngine's docs:
"Application code written for the Python environment must be written exclusively in Python. Extensions written in the C language are not supported"

Now whether you must use BeautifulSoup or not, it really depends on how you plan to use it. Update the question with details and I'll try to update here with other suggestions, if possible.

Comment: You _couldn't_, but as of Python 2.7 on AppEngine [you can](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27.html#Supported_Third-Party_Libraries).

Comment: Can't find lxml.  What happened?

Comment: @seriousdev Assuming you mean you can't find it on appengine using the 2.7 runtime: [look here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#Configuring_Libraries) - you need to manually enable lxml in order to use it.

Answer (score 12):

To add to Caio's revised answer, you can use `lxml` and this is how to do it:

In your `app.yaml` file, add the following:

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"   # or "latest"
```

Now `import lxml` will work in your Python script.

[Here is the link to the official documentation.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

Comment: There should not be a dash before "version: 2.3".

Comment: Unfortunately, GAE provides only an old version of lxml. GAE's "latest" version of lxml is missing the "safe_attrs" attribute, vital for implementing XSS security.