# Parsing HTML easily like PyQuery in Python 2.5

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am writing an app for GAE (Python 2.5) and I was wondering if there is any library like PyQuery (which runs on Python 2.6+).

All I have to do is to load an HTML file and get the content of a especific tag through its ID. In PyQuery, or even Python2.6's libraries like lxml, it is very easy, but I don't know how to do that with Python 2.5.

Can someone help me? ^^

Thank you guys. :)

Comment: PyQuery crucially depends on lxml, which is a third-party library available for Python 2.3 or later, fully including 2.5 and 2.6 -- and unfortunately _not_ available on GAE, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894696/python-lxml-on-app-engine . It's **not** an issue of 2.5 vs 2.6! Please edit your question to fix the wrong assertions and implications in question (which might confuse others), thanks.  As for your Q, the existing answers suggesting BeautifulSoup (which is pure-Python and thus just fine for GAE) are fine -- but, be sure to get BS 3.0.8.1, **not** BS 3.1!

Comment: What about BeautifulSoup version 3.2.0 with GAE? That's the present version..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a common choice for HTML parsing, and is compatible with Python 2.5.